# Can I prepend a PHP file using .htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

So I was reading Twitter a bit until I saw this tweet by [@DivineOmega](https://twitter.com/DivineOmega/status/696806187526983680):

[image: Img]

The perfect PHP error handler (pretty much), I coded it and I wanted to use it server-wide, but **How can I apply this file to all my PHP scripts?**

Comment: So you want every php file on your server encapsulated by this try catch block?

Comment: pretty much yes. I already read about set_error_handler, but that would require a include which would be too much work.

Comment: It would have been nice if you included the author of that tweet/exception handler. IMO.

Comment: @Jelle Sorry, included it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use phps `auto_prepend_file` and `auto_append_file` directives.

It works like loading every script on your server via `require_once()` right between the files specified by `auto_prepend_file` (Loaded before your script) and `auto_append_file` (Loaded right after your script).

To activate in `.htaccess`:

```
php_value auto_prepend_file "/path/to/file/before.php"
php_value auto_append_file "/path/to/file/after.php"
```

Or in `php.ini` (required when running in cgi-mode, affects wole webserver):

```
auto_prepend_file  = "/path/to/file/before.php"
auto_append_file   = "/path/to/file/after.php"
```

**before.php**

```
try {
```

**after.php**

```
} catch(Exception $e) {
  ...
}
```